# Select and add in columns in R

Tags: r

How can I select other columns in sf_MX dataframe to add in sumbyweek? I am stuck.

```
     sumbyweek <- sf_MX %>%
                        filter(CVE_ENT %in%  c("09","15","17")) %>%
                        group_by(CVE_ENT) %>%
                        summarise(across(starts_with('cumul')[13:32], 
                                  sum,na.rm = TRUE,.names = '{col}_total'))%>%
    select(Col1,col2) #unable to get the idea result
```

sf_MX Data Table:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3| Cumul1 |Cumul2 | Cumul3 …
```

Expected result:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Cumul1_total |Cumul2_total |Cumul3_total
```

Comment: Hey! The columns you want to select, do not exist. You can create them with `mutate()`.

Comment: What do you mean by do not exist? I thought it is in my sf_MX dataframe. Mind explaining?

Comment: how do I call the mutate columns. it is not adding to my new datatable

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
library(dplyr)
sumbyweek <- sf_MX %>%
                    filter(CVE_ENT %in%  c("09","15","17")) %>%
                    group_by(CVE_ENT) %>%
                    summarise(across(starts_with('cumul'), 
                              sum, na.rm = TRUE, .names = '{col}_total'))
```